# segmentation fault using c++ copy instead of memcpy

Tags: c++, copy, segmentation-fault

I'm using C++ copy algorithm to copy a string literal, (instead of memcpy) but I'm getting segmentation fault I don't know why though. here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // if using copy with regular pointers, there 
    // is no need to get an output iterator, ex:
    char* some_string = "this is a long string\n";
    size_t some_string_len = strlen(some_string) + 1;

    char* str_copy = new char(some_string_len);
    copy( some_string, some_string + some_string_len, str_copy);
    printf("%s", str_copy);

    delete str_copy;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a good reason you can't use `std::string`?

Comment: It's for learning purposes. I was trying out the copy algorithm with output iterators, and in a book that I'm reading now, describes that I can replace the iterators in the copy call with low level pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fix :

```
char* str_copy = new char[some_string_len];
                         ^ notice square bracket
```

Free memory using :

`delete [] str_copy;`

Comment: @ArmenB and before you ask why ? So, If `()` is used, the item is value-initialized.

Comment: @AmenB that would be the technical description for saying you were allocating a **single** char and initializing it to the value of `some_string_len`. I'm surprised your compiler didn't issue a warning about the down-convert between `int` and `char`.